# Tilt of OpenStreetMap with LeafletJs

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, leaflet

I am using LeafletJs as mapping library for OpenStreetMaps. Is there any method map.Tilt() in Leaflet api like google provides

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.8313284, -82.7251666),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    heading: 90,
    tilt: 30
});
```

I need not SATELLITE view. Recently i am viewing markers like this. I need to show in 20/30 degree angled the map.
[image]

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367898/tilt-of-openstreetmap-with-leafletjs

Comment: yep, I am finding my answer and nobody cares.

Comment: Nobody cares. Is this your take on not getting an answer to a non-trivial question within 30 minutes? Please, don't cross post, it just dilutes the value of both sites.

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin functionality for this in Leaflet, and no plugin to do it that I am aware of either.

You could maybe produce something like it with some CSS `transform3d` hack, but it would likely look pretty horrible.

In general, I think OpenLayers 3 might be more suited for pseudo-3d functionality. I have not used OpenLayers 3 myself, though.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using a css Transform, but it doesn't look great, but it works well enough for some things. The screenshot below uses the style: `transform: translate3d(-300px, -141px, 0px)` on the div containing the map.

[image: Using transform 3d]